# How can I change order of scripts in head in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need jquery.js would be first in the head then colorbox.js then my custom-script.js. My custom script depends on jquery and colorbox. But it always higher in the head of page then colorbox.js. I need to change that order. What should I do to do this? Sorry for my english.

```
<?php 

/*Functions file for child theme*/
define( 'OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/' );
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/options-framework.php';
function mychildtheme_setup() {
    show_admin_bar(false);
    wp_register_script( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery',     'jquery.colorbox-min'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main' );
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mychildtheme_setup');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mychildtheme_setup', 10000 );
?>
```

Comment: How do you calling your scripts with `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: I've put last version of my functions.php. I'm not sure how to define dependecy between my script and colorbox in the right way. Colorbox is enqued by another plugin in plugins php file. Now my script is disappeared from head of page.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the script with `wp_enqueue_script` and add jQuery as a dependency, that way wordpress takes care of the order

```
<?php 
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $dependency, $ver, $in_footer ); 
?>
```

so something like :

```
wp_register_script( 'colorbox', plugins_url('/path/colorbox.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'colorbox' );

wp_register_script( 'custom', plugins_url('/path/custom-script.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery', 'colorbox' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
```

Comment: If I did as you described, my custom script disappeared from head of page. Did you know why?

Comment: That's because I set the last argument to true, the one that is clearly marked $in_footer which includes the scripts at the bottom of the page. Just set the last argument to false instead, and the scripts will appear in the head.

Comment: I tried both false and true, but main.js never appeared in source code if there is array('jquery',     'jquery.colorbox-min') It appears only if it's without 'jquery.colorbox-min' like array('jquery') I don't know what I do wrong

Comment: The array should contain the handlers of other scripts, not the script files themselves, see the example above where the array contains `jquery`, which is built in to wordpress, and then just `colorbox`, which is the handler for the script above it.