# I need to change order of scripts in footer of my wordpress site so my custom main.js file loads last of all scripts

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is how I call my custom script in `functions.php` my child theme:

```
<?php 

/*Functions file for child theme*/
define( 'OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/' );
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/options-framework.php';
function mychildtheme_setup() {
    show_admin_bar(false);
    wp_register_script( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main' );
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mychildtheme_setup');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mychildtheme_setup', 10000 );
?>
```

But when I look in source code I see that my `main.js` loads before `contact-form.js` and I want my `main.js` script loads after that one.

How can I change the order so my script loads last of all scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Need answer still?
Similar question has been answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114473/wp-enqueue-script-how-to-change-loading-order-of-scripts.
Keyword is `$deps`.

Comment: You asked twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203793/how-can-i-change-order-of-scripts-in-head-in-wordpress.